# this.state.items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do `console.log(items)` I got ['a','b','c'] but I got error of map is not a function.

```
..    
    var Todo_list = React.createClass({
      getInitialState(){
        return { items:['a','b']}
      },
      addItem(item){
      this.setState({items:this.state.items.push(item)})
        console.log(this.state.items) // this is working
      },
      render() {
        return (
        <div>
         <TodoInput addItem={this.addItem} />

         {this.state.items.map((item,i) =>  <li key={i}>{item}</li> )}
         </div>
        );
      }
    });
..
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tehwajh2/ Try to add an item, I wonder why, I guess I've pushed it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `this.state.items.push(item);` seperately. It works

```
var TodoInput = React.createClass({
    handleAddItem(){
        var todo_val = this.refs.todo_val.value;
      this.props.addItem(todo_val);
  },
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input ref='todo_val' type="text" />
     <button onClick={this.handleAddItem}>Add</button>
     </div>
    );
  }
});

var Todo_list = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return { items:['a','b']}
  },
  addItem(item){
  console.log(item);
 this.state.items.push(item);
  this.setState({items: this.state.items});
    console.log(this.state.items) 
  },
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <TodoInput addItem={this.addItem} />
     {this.state.items.map(function(item, key) {
        return (
        <li key={key}> {item}</li>
      )

     })}
     </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <Todo_list />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tehwajh2/3/)

Comment: so I have to assign it to a variable then only assign to the state.items, correct?

Comment: No need, as shown in example you can directly push to state but outside of setstate function

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can use `.concat` instead of `.push`, because `.push` returns the **new length** of the array., length is `Number`, and `Number` does not have `.map` method that's why you get error

```
 this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat(item) })
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/tehwajh2/2/)

> The [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.
>
> The [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method returns a new array comprised of the array on
>   which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided
>   as arguments.